# how import/copy a file or directory into Desktop ubuntu 14.04 laptop

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, laptop

My Dell Precision laptop has a funny Desktop (it is 14.04 with KDE) as different from my table-top comp with 12.04 and any other comps I used before, I don't see any directory named "Desktop",  but I can see a few files or directories I've put there in the past, and now they are on the screen. There must be some "mark" to be put on the file for it to show up on the Desktop, or something else has to be done? (In all the other comps, I'd simply copy a file or directory into that "Desktop" directory, and that was it...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, it was simple, yet not too obvious. First: indeed, there is NO Desktop folder (at lest in my version of ubuntu, 14.04 with KDE). Second: when I tried to drug the folder or file of my choice from DOLPHIN window into the Desktop screen, the system simply refused to react. SOLUTION: click on a controlling "quarter glob" in the upper right corner of the Desktop screen, and then click at "Unlock widgets" in the menu. After that go back to Dolphin window, and from it drug whatever object you need into the desirable place on the Desktop screen (and at that choose "icon" mode out of those offered in the little menu). Then go back to the "quarter glob" and its menu, and click now on "Lock widgets". That's it. You can use now a new icon in a regular way.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're already looking at your laptop's "Desktop" folder?  From the commandline, try the **`pwd`** command to show where you are.

Another command to try is **`ls -A ~`** which will do a listing of (almost) everything in your home directory.  You really should find a "Desktop" folder included in the listing.

Comment: Yes, of course, I've done that,, and also looked at Dolphin window; still the same thing: there is no dedicated Desktop directory/folder.